# Why does this 'mov' instruction result in extraneous bytes in the upper bits of the destination register?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am attempting to debug a crash in a very simple for loop.  The C++ is very similar to:

```
   bool test(uint64_t value) {
       auto iter = std::find_if(..., ..., [value](const auto& element) {
           return element.proxy ? element.proxy->value == value : false; //element.proxy is a pointer
       }
       ...
   }
```

The generated assembly is very straightforward, and is basically an unrolled for loop

```
  ...
  6b5b72:   4c 8b 6d 08             mov    r13,QWORD PTR [rbp+0x8]
  6b5b76:   4d 85 ed                test   r13,r13
  6b5b79:   74 06                   je     6b5b81 
  6b5b7b:   41 3b 55 00             cmp    edx,DWORD PTR [r13+0x0]
  6b5b7f:   74 7f                   je     6b5c00 
  6b5b81:   4c 8b 6d 48             mov    r13,QWORD PTR [rbp+0x48]
  6b5b85:   4d 85 ed                test   r13,r13
  6b5b88:   74 0a                   je     6b5b94 
  6b5b8a:   41 3b 55 00             cmp    edx,DWORD PTR [r13+0x0]
  6b5b8e:   0f 84 bc 01 00 00       je     6b5d50 
  6b5b94:   4c 8b ad 88 00 00 00    mov    r13,QWORD PTR [rbp+0x88]
  6b5b9b:   4d 85 ed                test   r13,r13
  6b5b9e:   74 0a                   je     6b5e10
  6b5ba0:   41 3b 55 00             cmp    edx,DWORD PTR [r13+0x0]   ;We will crash here
  6b5ba4:   0f 84 66 02 00 00       je     6b5e10 
  6b5baa:   4c 8b ad c8 00 00 00    mov    r13,QWORD PTR [rbp+0xc8]
  6b5bb1:   4d 85 ed                test   r13,r13
  6b5bb4:   74 0a                   je     6b5bc0 
  6b5bb6:   41 3b 55 00             cmp    edx,DWORD PTR [r13+0x0]
  6b5bba:   0f 84 80 01 00 00       je     6b5d40 
  6b5bc0:   48 81 c5 00 01 00 00    add    rbp,0x100
  6b5bc7:   48 39 c5                cmp    rbp,rax
  ...
  (note: there might be slight transcription errors in the raw hex and je addresses which I am attempting to fix)
```

The program crashes at line 6b5ba0.  The value of $r13 is way outside of what I would expect to be a valid memory address

```
(gdb) p/x $r13
$130 = 0x40007f7bd5b3fde8
```

The problem is though, based on the assembly I would expect $r13 to be equal to the 64-bit value $rbp+0x88 is pointing to.  If we look at that value in gdb we get this:

```
(gdb) p *(uint64_t **)($rbp+0x88)
$132 = (uint64_t *) 0x7f7bd5b3fde8
```

This is the value in $r13, except with 0x4000 prepended to the address.  I have also verified the data at 0x7f7bd5b3fde8 is what I would expect. Looking at the output I do not know how this is possible, especially since I have to assume the previous instructions that correspond to unrolling the loop did not trigger this.

How did those extra bytes get there?

Comment: Can you post enough code that your example is reproducible?

Comment: Does this reproduce consistently? Did you break on 6b5b94, ensure that `[rbp+0x88]` is what you expect, then single step and verify that `r13` is wrong?

Comment: @thatotherguy Unfortunately not easily reproducible, this example is from a core file.

Comment: @MichaelPetch The code is single threaded.  I am really unsure how something could clobber the memory between the segfault and the generation of the core dump.

Comment: Could it have hit the `je     6b5e10`, done something, then come back?  Does the core dump confirm that no other threads have been started by the runtime or a dependency? Have you run a memtest recently?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct disassembly. It makes no sense to me that `74 0a` and `0f 84 66 02 00 00` have the same branch target of `6b5e10` when there is only one other instruction between them

Comment: Does your code consistently crash at this exact same location every time it is run?

Comment: Your disassembly is definitely wrong. `74 0a` at `6b5b9e` is `je 6b5baa`, not `je 6b5e10`. Assuming you didn't edit what you showed us by hand, something is seriously wrong.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I did clean this up by hand to remove a lot of uninterpretable-without-the-source noise, I might have introduced small errors.

Comment: Indeed, `0x40007f7bd5b3fde8` is non-canonical (not 48 or 57-bit sign-extended), so dereferencing it is guaranteed to fault.  Is your CPU over-clocked?  Or could your RAM be failing?  That could maybe explain "loading" a value that isn't in memory.

Comment: Some may get why I ask this not so serious question. Are you running this on MacOS inside a docker container?

Comment: @MichaelPetch No, this is running under Linux installed on bare hardware with no containerization.  I'd love to know why this is relevant.